# Forward reference error in a for loop Scala

Tags: scala, variables, scala-breeze

This is a code that is written in Scala :

```
for (i <- 0 until 10) {
  if (i > 0) {
    val new = theta(i * 5)
  }
  // using variable new

  val theta = DenseVector.zeros[Int]((i + 1) * 10)
  // doing operations on theta
}
```

every iteration has own variables and order of variables can't change because between them doing some operations.

when i running this code it shows this error:

```
Wrong forward reference
```

how can i resolve this problem?

Comment: `lazy val theta` solves ordering problem.

Comment: Code that compiles is more useful to demonstrate your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `theta` before `if` expression by making `theta` method.

```
def theta(i: Int) = DenseVector.zeros[Int]((i + 1) * 10)
for (i <- 0 until 10) {
  if (i > 0) {
    val new = theta(i * 5)
  }
  // doing operations on theta
}
```

Comment: Thank you @yanana , but when i want to assign values to every element of this vector, it shows " Too many argument for method theta (Int)"

Comment: How do you assign values to the vector?